# Angular e2e - should render title in a h1 tag

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-e2e

I am developing my own website. I am new to Angular and just based on learing and online posts, I started developing my website. While running tests, I faced an error for getting h1 tag value.

I developed routes. One of the routes that AppComponent loads is HomeComponent in which h1 tag is available.

In app.component.spec.ts file, below is failed to get value of h1.

```
it('should render title in a h1 tag', () => {
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
fixture.detectChanges();
const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to jc-web!');});
```

Can anyone suggest how I can fetch h1 value from HomeComponent in the above code?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the h1 value inside HomeComponent, which is nested inside AppComponent, you'll need to either provide the actual HomeComponent in your TestBed:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ]
});
```

or else provide a stubbed version for your test to use. If you choose to provide the actual component, you must also include all of its dependencies. There's a more detailed explanation on how to test nested components in the Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#nested-component-tests).

Comment: On a related note, Karma is usually used for unit tests, meaning you shouldn't need to check the DOM of another component. Is there a reason you don't want to put your test in the spec.ts file for HomeComponent?

Comment: I moved my above code to home.component.spec.ts file and testing passed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the following code in the app.component.ts file.

title = 'the title';

```
it(`should have as title 'the title'`, () => {
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
expect(app.title).toEqual('the title');
```

});

This is in the app.component.spec.ts file

```
export class AppComponent {
title = ‘the title’ ;
}
```

This is in the app.component.ts file